# parsing an array of address from a proc file in linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am writing a variable number of addresses to a proc entry, like

`echo  num_addr  addr1 addr2 addr3... addr_n  > /proc/memory_address`

(where `num_addr` is the number of addresses), e.g.

`echo 2 0x1100 0x3300 > /proc/memory_address`

How can I parse this information inside the function corresponds to echo /proc/memory_address?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is a "proc write function"?

Comment: not sure what your question is, do you mean `fscanf`?

Comment: You say you want to "write" something. You also say you want to "parse" something (which sounds like you want to read it). So what do you really want to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char *str= "5          0x333    0x232323 555 22323 2323";
        char *entptr;
        int nCount;
        int i;
        unsigned long ulArr[5];

        printf("\n String: %s", str);

        nCount = strtol(str, &entptr, 10);

        printf("\n NCount is %d", nCount);

        printf(" Endptr = %s", entptr);

        while(*entptr == ' ' || *entptr == '0' || *entptr == 'x' || *entptr == '\t') entptr++;

        i = 0;
        while(i<nCount)
        {
                str = entptr;
                ulArr[i] = strtol(str, &entptr, 10);
                printf("\n ulArr[%d] = %u", i, ulArr[i]);

                printf(" Endptr = %s", entptr);
                while(*entptr == ' ' || *entptr == '0' || *entptr == 'x' || *entptr == '\t') entptr++;
                printf(" Endptr = %s", entptr);
                //while(*entptr != ' ' && *entptr!='\0') entptr++;
                i++;
        }
        return 0;
}
```